# Can't login to Magento Connect Manager - 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, error, login, 404-page

I've been banging my head against my keyboard with this problem! A couple days ago it worked just fine, however now I cannot login to my Magento Connect Manager. It redirects me to the 404 page of my root folder (magento is in a subfolder).

**A little bit about my setup...**

I have magento installed in a subfolder (public_html/magento)

I have Opencart installed in my root folder (that is currently my live site
I am testing magento in the subfolder and preparing to launch soon).

When I try to login to Magento Connect it redirects me to the 404 page of my opencart site in my root folder.

**Some things I have ALREADY tried...**

Changing permissions of "downloader" folder and it's index.php to 0777, 0755, 0644, etc. Multiple combinations.

Re-installing magento

Double checked base_url rewrites in my backend config (as well as in the database)

Changing my admin password

Deleting the last extension I had installed before I noticed it stopped working

I'm hoping someone can help me! I have gone through everything I can find on google and unfortunately nothing is working. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The Magento Connect Manager is an independent web app placed in downloader inside magento root, depending on your webserver configuration you have to create rewrites there, it only gets login state and some configs from magento, its not build on top of magento.

Comment: Ok, do you have any suggestions?